# Microservice Authentication on Azure Kubernetes With Gigya

Tags: api, azure, kubernetes, gateway

I have a set of Microservices in Docker containers in AKS which need to serve only authenticated requests. 
I have another Microservice which authenticates with Gigya.

Is there any way in AKS wherein I can put an APIM or Gateway in the middle and have unauthenticated requests to be sent to the Authenticate Microservice and the authenticated requests to be sent to the corresponding Microservice within AKS.

I have been looking for sources on the net for this, but haven’t been able to find any. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

How about [the ORY Oathkeeper](https://github.com/ory/oathkeeper)?

It works together with [ORY Keto](https://github.com/ory/keto) and [ORY Hydra](https://github.com/ory/hydra).